# What does an exclamation mark in Lua do?

Tags: lua, logical-operators, negation

Question is in the title, really. I saw someone use this earlier and I didn't know what the `!` was used for.

```
local lowestIndex = 0;
local lowestValue = false;
for k, v in ipairs(playerElement) do
    if !lowestValue or v.value < lowestValue then
        lowestIndex = k;
        lowestValue = v;
    end
end
```

Comment: It appears to be a syntax error. `!` is logical "not" in some languages, but Lua uses `not`. Where did you see that code? Did it actually run? Are you sure it's Lua code?

Comment: You're correct. I just tested it and it came out as `lua: test.lua:2: unexpected symbol near '!'`

Comment: I tried to fix this answer to replace the `!` (which is C syntax) by `not` (the equivalent Lua symbol), but, thanks to the requirement that you can't edit a question if you add a too low number of character, I gave up.

Comment: @michaelmeyer: I'm glad you didn't make that edit. The question was about the meaning of the `!` character; changing it to `not` would have invalidated it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have said, `!` normally has no function in Lua, and the code you posted would not normally be valid. However, it's quite trivial to extend Lua's parser to allow for custom syntax, and it's not unheard of for projects which embed Lua to add "more familiar" C-style syntax such as `!var` and `!=` in addition to `not var` and `~=`. One notable project which does this is [Garry's Mod](http://maurits.tv/data/garrysmod/wiki/wiki.garrysmod.com/indexba22.html), and I'm sure there are others.

Of course, using custom syntax when the normal syntax is available (or customising it in the first place) is best avoided, if possible, to avoid exactly this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntax error.

Some languages, mostly C and its relatives, use `!` as a logical "not" operator, but Lua uses the `not` keyword instead, and does not use `!` for anything as far as I know (not even as part of the inequality operator; it uses `~=` where C uses `!=`).

You appear to have gotten hold of some Lua code written by someone who doesn't know that.